# Selenium IDE error timed out after 0ms

Tags: selenium, timeout, selenium-ide

I got various tests running with selenium...
now there is the problem that the tests sometimes give me the error timed out after 0ms!
is there any way to fix this problem? I already tried everything I know...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

possible problem is that selenium is unable to locate web element which may be caused by improper css selector or xpath or some other way you locating web elements.
Try to veify wheter you've located properly web element in firebug(ffox addon)
Could you provide the whole stacktrace error and piece of html with the element you try to perform actions on.